# Orchard CMS: Content Item Get Field By Name in View

Tags: orchardcms, content-type

I have created a custom content type (via the admin UI) that consists mostly of text fields. I know how to position the fields using zones and Placement.info but for simplicity I would like to use a single view template and to just arrange the fields by name instead of having to use Placement.info. Is there a good way to reference the fields by name from the content item in my MVC view?

So for example, I have a template named Content-MyContentType-Detail.cshtml. Instead of the generic

`@Display(Model.Content)`

I would like to be able to do something like

`@Display(...MyField...)
@Display(...MyOtherField...)`

Is there a way to explicitly render a field by name that is associated with my content item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shape Tracing module to view model properties and how to get access to content parts.

Then in your template you can use something like this:

```
<h3>@Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title - £@Model.ContentItem.Product.Fields[1].Value</h3>
<p>@Model.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't just want to access the field's properties, but rather would like its shape rendered in-place, but like it would be when using placement (i.e. using the existing template), then read this article, which describes how to do direct rendering without placement: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/02/13/easy-content-templates-for-orchard-take-2.aspx